# Checkbox from Element Plus styling the Checkbox Button

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am using *Vue 3* and the library *Element Plus*. I want to change the **hover**, **active** and the **select** **color** of the Checkbox Button I am using. This does not seem to work. I pretty much copied the code from there so you can view the source code or test it in the playground.
Thanks for help in advance!

This is what I am using: https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/checkbox.html#button-style

I have tried using :hover and :active selectors. Maybe I am using them wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for active you can use this

```
.el-checkbox-button.is-checked .el-checkbox-button__inner {
    color: var(--el-checkbox-button-checked-text-color);
    background-color: #208eff;
    border-color: var(--el-checkbox-button-checked-border-color);
    box-shadow: -1px 0 0 0 var(--el-color-primary-light-7);
}
```

and for hover

```
.el-checkbox-button__inner:hover {
    color: var(--el-color-primary);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I still do not understand your syntax much. Could you give me some reference, so I can learn this.

Comment: Could you also tell me how to change the blue outline color when I deselect the button?